# Asynchronous HTTP call doesn't work

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on an Android app (min API 8) and I want to make an activity where there is a preloader GIF running while some tasks are executed in the background.

These tasks involve connection to a database and queries. So in some way, I want to achieve something that involves techniques like you would use to make a progress bar.

I know I can't make a connection in the main thread in Java so I made a class that does this in another thread. The connection works fine, but I can't make the whole behaviour work properly. More precisely, if I use `thread.join()`then the main thread is blocked (which is the opposite of what I want) and if I don't use it, the code of the main thread goes on and finishes before the background process has terminated.

Can someone help me with this please ?

This is the class I created to manage POST queries to an URL :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Request
{
    private URL m_url;
    private StringBuilder m_parameters;
    private HttpURLConnection m_connection;

    public Request(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            m_url = new URL(url);
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException exception)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        m_connection = null;
        m_parameters = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void put(String key, String value)
    {
        if(m_parameters.length() != 0)
            m_parameters.append('&');

        try
        {
            m_parameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            m_parameters.append('=');
            m_parameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException exception)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void sendRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = m_parameters.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

            m_connection = (HttpURLConnection) m_url.openConnection();

            m_connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
            m_connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            m_connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
            m_connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length));
            m_connection.setDoOutput(true);
            m_connection.getOutputStream().write(data);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private String getResponse()
    {
        String response = "";

        try
        {
            if(m_connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                int c;

                do {
                    c = reader.read();
                    response += (char) c;
                }
                while (c >= 0);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        m_connection.disconnect();
        return response;
    }

    public String get()
    {
        final AtomicReference<String> response = new AtomicReference<>();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                sendRequest();
                response.set(getResponse());
            }
        });

        thread.start();
/*
        try
        {
            thread.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException exception)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
*/
        return response.get();
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it in the main thread (the activity) :

```
Request request = new Request("http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dump&html&sleep=5");
request.put("name", "bob");
String response = request.get();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use OkHttp. it's way easier.

Comment: Why don't you use an AsynkTask _with a finishCallback_ to get the data from the server?

Comment: `System.exit(1);` **Really** ? See https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html

Comment: @Fildor : IntentService seems complicated for what I want to do.
@TimCastelijns : can you give more details please ? How do I use a callback in this situation ?

@user6547359 : I hoped I could do without `AsyncTask`, it will take me time to re-do everything.

@Vucko I'd prefer to use native Java

Comment: "I'd prefer to use native Java" - Well, you'll run into walls then. You are on Android. Things are handled differently from your average J2SE Application. For loading data in background, Android gives you IntentService, Loaders (but since you want to support Plattform 8 these probably don't apply), AsyncTask or Handler. Plain Threads as you would do in J2SE most of the time are not so well suited.

Comment: @Fildor : ok, I'll take a look at these. I think I will use AsyncTask. I'll post a solution if I find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally solved that problem using standard `IntentService`of Android :

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

This tutorial helped a lot too :

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183

Here is my new class `Request`:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Set;

public class Request extends IntentService
{
    private URL m_url;
    private StringBuilder m_parameters;
    private HttpURLConnection m_connection;

    public Request()
    {
        super("Request");

        m_url = null;
        m_connection = null;
        m_parameters = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void put(String key, String value)
    {
        if(m_parameters.length() != 0)
            m_parameters.append('&');

        try
        {
            m_parameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            m_parameters.append('=');
            m_parameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException exception)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void sendRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = m_parameters.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

            m_connection = (HttpURLConnection) m_url.openConnection();

            m_connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
            m_connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            m_connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
            m_connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length));
            m_connection.setDoOutput(true);
            m_connection.getOutputStream().write(data);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private String getResponse()
    {
        String response = "";

        try
        {
            if(m_connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                int c;

                do {
                    c = reader.read();
                    response += (char) c;
                }
                while (c >= 0);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        m_connection.disconnect();
        return response;
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();

        for(String key : keys)
            put(key, bundle.getString(key));

        try
        {
            m_url = new URL(bundle.getString("url"));
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException exception)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        sendRequest();
        String response = getResponse();

        Intent broadcast = new Intent();
        broadcast.setAction(ReadyActivity.ResponseReceiver.m_broadcastKey);
        broadcast.putExtra("response", response);
        sendBroadcast(broadcast);
    }
}
```

Here is the `ResponseReceiver`subclass of my main activity :

```
 public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public static final String m_broadcastKey = "Uz258e3wZm77Z3Tdebn7PqgW3CLBJ8";

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String response = intent.getStringExtra("response");

            clear();

            ((TextView) m_widgets.get("text")).setText("Finally found someone !" + response);
            show(m_widgets.get("text"));

            ((Button) m_widgets.get("button1")).setText("OK let's do this !");
            show(m_widgets.get("button1"));

            ((Button) m_widgets.get("button2")).setText("Later ?");
            show(m_widgets.get("button2"));

            unregisterReceiver(m_receiver);
        }
    }
```

Then I also had to instantiate the `ResponseReceiver` in the activity:

```
private ResponseReceiver m_receiver;
...
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.m_broadcastKey);
m_receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
registerReceiver(m_receiver, filter);
```

And finally call the service :

```
Intent service = new Intent(this, Request.class);
ArrayList<CharSequence> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
service.putExtra("url", "http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dump&html&sleep=10");
service.putExtra("username", "bob");
service.putExtra("age", "20");
startService(service);
```

Maybe it will help someone in the future.

Comment: For anyone seeing this, you'd be much better off using Retrofit, Volley, or at least OkHttp than doing it this way.